# NFC Reader APP, Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

We have an Android NFC Reader APP was working perfect now it has errors and the APP gets crashed.

```
2023-01-22 15:09:14.813 3602-3615/? E/PRM_CONFIG_Parser: get_custom_config not found
2023-01-22 15:09:14.830 4162-4351/? E/PostureManager: fail to get service
2023-01-22 15:09:14.832 4162-4351/? E/PostureManager: fail to get service
2023-01-22 15:09:14.834 4162-4351/? E/PostureManager: fail to get service
2023-01-22 15:09:14.884 12662-12662/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.ngf132, PID: 12662
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.ngf132/com.myapp.ngf132.Nfc_reader}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.myapp.ngf132: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

i have checked multiple questions i could not figure out the issue,

These are the imports i have

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.FormatException;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
```

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i needed to replace this code.

```
// pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```